# Amend Stored Procedure to Ignore Duplicate Records

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, primary-key

I need to make the below amendment to this stored procedure

```
create or replace PROCEDURE                 "USP_IMPORT_FOBTPP_DATA" 
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO FINIMP.FOBT_PARTPAYMENT
SELECT
PART_PAYMENT_ID,
ISSUING_SHOP,
TILL_NUMBER,
SLIP_NUMBER,
FOBT_NUMBER,
WHO_PAID,
WHEN_PAID,
AMOUNT_LEFT_TO_PAY,
FOBT_VALUE,
STATUS
FROM IMPORTDB.CLN_FOBTPP;

COMMIT;
END;
```

In order to skip any records that would result in a primary key violation, this is so the dataload process does not break.

```
Source Table
CREATE TABLE "FINIMP"."FOBT_PARTPAYMENT" 
(   "PART_PAYMENT_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
"ISSUING_SHOP" CHAR(4 BYTE), 
"TILL_NUMBER" NUMBER(3,0), 
"SLIP_NUMBER" NUMBER(*,0), 
"FOBT_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
"WHO_PAID" CHAR(20 BYTE), 
"WHEN_PAID" DATE, 
"AMOUNT_LEFT_TO_PAY" NUMBER(19,4), 
"FOBT_VALUE" NUMBER(19,4), 
"STATUS" CHAR(2 BYTE)
);

ALTER TABLE "FINIMP"."FOBT_PARTPAYMENT" ADD CONSTRAINT "PK_FOBT_PP" PRIMARY KEY ("PART_PAYMENT_ID", "ISSUING_SHOP", "WHEN_PAID")
```

I am new to PL/SQL, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this, and the best method depends on your environment/requirements. Is the `CLN_FOBTPP` table considerably large? Is the `USP_IMPORT_FOBTPP_DATA` procedure called frequently, and does it need to meet certain performance criteria? These are all things you should consider.

One way to do this would be to start with the query that you use.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE "USP_IMPORT_FOBTPP_DATA" 
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO FINIMP.FOBT_PARTPAYMENT
SELECT ...
FROM IMPORTDB.CLN_FOBTPP;
```

This will return all of the rows of data from `IMPORTDB.CLN_FOBTP` and insert them into `FINIMP.FOBT_PARTPAYMENT`. Instead, you could control for this by doing:

```
INSERT INTO FINIMP.FOBT_PARTPAYMENT
SELECT ...
FROM IMPORTDB.CLN_FOBTPP WHERE PART_PAYMENT_ID NOT IN (FINIMP.FOBT_PARTPAYMENT)
```

This would go through the `FOBT_PARTPAYMENT` table and check to see if a row's `PART_PAYMENT_ID` existed in the table before doing the insert. However, this can be prohibitively expensive if the table is large or if you have performance requirements.

Another way would be to create a temp table for each time the procedure is called, store the values in that temp table, and then add the new rows after validating the data. This would look something like:

```
create global temporary table temp_USP_table ("PART_PAYMENT_ID" NUMBER(*,0), "ISSUING_SHOP" CHAR(4 BYTE),...) on commit delete rows;
create or replace PROCEDURE "USP_IMPORT_FOBTPP_DATA" 
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO temp_USP_table
SELECT ...
FROM IMPORTDB.CLN_FOBTPP;
```

From there, you can do a number of things. You could use the same procedure to add the new rows from the temp table into the `FINIMP.FOBT_PARTPAYMENT` table:

```
delete from temp_USP_table where PART_PAYMENT_ID in FINIMP.FOBT_PARTPAYMENT;
insert into FINIMP.FOBT_PARTPAYMENT select * from temp_USP_table;
```

Or you could create a new procedure to load the new data from the `temp_USP_table` into the `FINIMP.FOBT_PARTPAYMENT` table, in case you'd like to do something additional to the new data before it's added to the table. Since you reference a data load, I would recommend going the temporary table route because it should allow you to load the data without issue. Once the data is loaded, you can worry about adding it to the proper table(s).

Comment: Wow what a great answer, the CLN_FOBTPP table is cleared down each day and will have a maximum of 1000 records at best at the moment.

Comment: While it may currently only have a max of 1000 at any moment, this may not always be the case - you might get asked to use this same process to load 10K records next year or even next month. While 1000 records is small, it wouldn't hurt to "future proof" this now if there is a chance you might have to later. And glad I could help, please remember to mark as answer if that gives you what you need :)